# to print a triangle of hash '#' and stars '*' in python

Tags: python

I m trying to print the following triangle in python, but not able to

```
*#####
**####
***###
****##
*****#
```

I am only able to print '*', but not hashes.

here's my code to print '*'

```
max = 6
for x in range(1,max+1):
    for y in range(1,x+1):
        print '*',

    print
```

Comment: Don't call a variable in your script `max` or like any other built-in function. You overwrite the name of this function. Big nono.

Comment: @Piinthesky : noted, will avoid that

Answer (score 7):

```
length = 6
for x in range(1, length+1):
    print(x * '*' + (length - x) * '#')  # integer * (string), concatenate the string integer times
```

Comment: Clean. Should probably explain the use of `*` in the string build though.

Comment: Good answer! I allowed myself the freedom to edit your answer and rename `max` to `length` in order to not override the builtin-function `max`. Also added brackets for the print to be compatible with Python 3.

Comment: @alfasin Wasnt there when I commented

Answer (score 0):

How to Print * in a triangle shape in python?

```
      *
     * *
    * * *
   * * * *
  * * * * *
```

This is one of the coding interview questions.

```
def print_triangle(n):
    for i, j in zip(range(1,n+1), range(n,0,-1)):
       print(" "*j, '* '*i, " "*j)
print_triangle(5)
```

Comment: Hi Paresh, Added details